# Remove leading zeros in a List of objects, then Join

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have two objects: requests and accts. Requests has a attribute FkDebitor with a debitor ID. accts also has an AccountCode which is similar to the FkDebitor but the ID is filled with leading zeros. I need to remove the leading zeros to be able to join these two together:

```
List<Requests> requests = context.Requests.ToList();
List<AutolineAccts> accts = AlContext.AutolineAccts.ToList();

 IEnumerable < dynamic > result = (from request in requests
                       join account in accts
                            on request.FkDebitor.ToString() equals account.AccountCode.TrimStart(new Char[] { '0' })
                        select new 
                        {
                            ID = request.PkRequest.ToString(),
                            Location = request.FkLocation,
                            RequestDate = request.RequestDate.Value,
                            Requestor = request.FkRequestor,
                            DebitorNr = request.FkDebitor.ToString(),
                            NewDebit = request.Debit.ToString(),
                            ApprovalStatus = request.ApprovalStatus.ToString(),
                            RecommendationStatus = request.RecommendationStatus.ToString(),
                            DebitorName = account.CustomerSname,
                            Limit = account.CreditLimit
                        }).ToList();
```

I tried to trim the AccountCode in the join statement but i receive an empty result set, although there are numbers in both sets that should be matched (e.g. 5371 in FkDebitor and 005371 in AccountCode).

Any idea how I can get this thing working? I already tried to trim the leading zeros in the list before i fire the sql part but my code doesn't do anything with the accts.AccountCode attribute:

```
for (int i = 0; i < accts.Count(); i++)
            {
                accts.ElementAt(i).AccountCode = accts.ElementAt(i).AccountCode.TrimStart('0');
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried figuring out how to do it in SQL Server?  Once you do that, these functions (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/sqlclient-for-ef-functions) might be useful.  Unfortunately, SQL's `TRIM` function is not as useful as C#'s

Comment: I'm not directly working on the server level, thus not using native MS SQL commands. I would prefer to solve this issue by using plain EF core.